# Pandas dataframe: Based on some current row R1, find another row R2 for which all rows in between match a condition

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Given the following exemplary dataframe/series,
I have - for some given reason - identified row number 6 as the relevant base row and I now want to find the row where the unbroken series of ones started (in this case that is row 3).

I explicitly do not want to find the first row containing a one (which would be row 0) but I want to find the row for which the following holds: Starting from our base row (row 6) go up until you don't find a one anymore. Then return the index of this row.

```
    A
0   1
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   0
9   0
```

I hope this is somewhat clear. Thanks for any suggestions!

Also I am grateful for approaches that can be generically adapted to cases where for example

- the base row itself does not have a one itself (in that case its about finding the start of some previous series of ones within this column)
- maybe I am not interested in the one-series that was previous but rather the one that followed.

Comment: As quick approach would be to create a new column "change_id" and count that up whenever the column "A" changes. Then you can easily search for the lowest row number with the same id as "6". The other approach is to walk downwards from 6 until A changes and find the last unchanged row. The first approach is good, if you need the value for all rows, the second, if you only need it a few times.

Comment: I like your approach, although what I have is not IDs, but just that boolean series. If I make a columns that shows if that series changed, I'd still be left with the task of identifying the closest "change" relative to row number 6..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that should be performant:

```
n = 6
# a new group id is formed every time the value changes in A
df["group_id"] = np.cumsum(df.A != df.A.shift())

# get group for n, return first column of that group    
group = df.group_id.iloc[n]
df[df.group_id == group].head(1)
```

df with group_id; this can be dropped as needed:

```
   A  group_id
0  1         1
1  0         2
2  0         2
3  1         3
4  1         3
5  1         3
6  1         3
7  1         3
8  0         4
9  0         4
```

result:

```
   A  group_id
3  1         3
```

Comment: great solution. Thats just the key I was looking for :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any built-in method for that, but you can most certainly use a for loop.

```
start = 6  # By any method you have identified
while start > 0:
    if df['A'][start] == 1 
       start -= 1
    else 
        break
print(start + 1)
```

Now, to access that row you can do something like

```
df.iloc[start+1, :]
```

If you want to go downwards

```
while start < df.shape[1]:
    # same if
        start += 1
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. Yes I also thought about looping over the rows starting at my base row. Although I feel this is rather hacky as looping is often considered an anti-pattern when working with dataframes.

Comment: Yes, we should avoid iterating over rows whenever possible. I'm also curious to see if there is a hack to it!